# Jquery Autocomplete Using Input Array

Tags: jquery, html

I have created an autocomplete jquery, but this script is only for an non array input. How do I change this script in order to be used in an array input.
This is a sample script of html code:

```
<table>
  <?php 
     for(i=0,i<7,i++){
  ?>
  <tr>
     <td>
          <input type="text" name="gaccnum[]" />
     </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
     }
  ?>
</table>
```

And this is a script for autocomplete in javascript:

```
    $(function () {
    var collectionArray = $.map(collection, function (value, key) { return { value: value, data: key }; });

    // Initialize ajax autocomplete:
    $('input[name="gaccnum[]"]').each(function(key,value){
        $(this).autocomplete({
            // serviceUrl: '/autosuggest/service/url',
            lookup: collectionArray,
            lookupFilter: function (suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
                var re = new RegExp('\\b' +       $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
            return re.test(suggestion.value);
            },
            onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' +    suggestion.data);
            },
            onHint: function (hint) {
            $('#autocomplete-ajax-x').val(hint);
            },
            onInvalidateSelection: function () {
                $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: none');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This module works only in the first row.

Comment: Isn't there a typo : is it `$('#selction-ajax')` or `$('#selection-ajax')`?
I am not sure you gave enough of your HTML code to answer.

Comment: I mean the javascript is like this :   $('input[name="gaccnum[]"]').each(function(key,value){
        $(this).autocomplete({
            // serviceUrl: '/autosuggest/service/url',
            lookup: collectionArray,
            lookupFilter: function (suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
                var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
                return re.test(suggestion.value);
            }                                                         });
});